# How do you load information from a .txt file in batch?

Tags: batch-file, save, load

So I have been doing some small batch programs lately but I can't manage to make the batch file load information. This is how i would do it.

```
:load_game
)
set /p something=
) > something.txt
```

In the txt file:

something_is_awesome

That is it^^

If i remember it right that is how you SAVE a file... now how do you LOAD it in a similar way?

Note: I would like to do multiple at once!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to WRITE a line to a file use `echo my_information>something.txt` (overwriting)

to READ a line from a file use `set /p something=<something.txt`

to write or read several lines:

```
echo First line>something.txt
echo second line>>something.txt
echo and a third one>>something.txt
```

or if you want to write all of them in one go:

```
@echo off
rem writing
(
  echo First line
  echo second line
  echo and a third one
)>something.txt

type something.txt
rem reading a
<something.txt (
  set /p one=
  set /p two=
  set /p three=
)
echo a. %one% %two% %three%

rem reading b
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a i=0
<something.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (something.txt) do (
    set /a i+=1
    set /p read[!i!]=
  )
)
echo b. %read[1]% %read[2]% %read[3]%
```

NOTE: contrary to what seems logical, `set /p var=<<file.txt` does NOT work.

Comment: I was more about if there was any possibility to do multiple (more/many) at once, if you know plz share :)

Comment: Thank you so much, wish i could upvote but i have too bad reputation :(

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, you can accept it by klicking on the checkmark. This tells everyone, it's solved.

Comment: @Stephan you can vote for his question to let him won some reputation :) 
I just vote for you and for his question ;)

Comment: in "reading b" I do not understand the interest of this `<something.txt (( ... set /p read[!i!]= ))` when the following would be enough `( ... set read[!i!]=%%a )`

Comment: @Paul yes, also possible (and even better), but I tried to stay at one method to not confuse the OP, who is obviously quite new to Batch.