# Batch file data -- writing to file, reading it back?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How do I get a Batch file to store data? I've tried using Text files and Dat files but no luck. Could anyone help me out?

I tried this for storing a `name`:

```
echo %name% >name.txt
```

but I'm finding it hard making it extract the `name` data and printing it in a batch file.

Comment: What do you want the batch file to do? please describe the desired output; what is the value of variable `name`? do you want its value or its name being written into file `name.txt`?

Comment: @aschipfl - he's trying to store values in an external file and then read those values in to set variable values via the script later on. It doesn't matter what the value of `%name%` is.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30686084/2152082)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you load information from a .txt file in batch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686018/how-do-you-load-information-from-a-txt-file-in-batch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to save the data like this :

```
@echo off
set "name=Jaden"
>name.txt echo name=%name%
```

And to get the value again. Just evaluate the line(s) in name.txt 
like this :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (name.txt) do set %%a
echo name --^> %name%
```

Answer (score 0):

First set the value and then if you echo to a file redirect, it will send the content value to a file.

```
set name=Jaden
echo %name% > name.txt
```

then it will work.

Comment: That part has already been established. He's trying to set the `%name%` variable based on the contents of `name.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `set /p name=<name.txt`

Comment: Did you try it ?  `set /p` is better

Comment: Sorry, got sloppy. Yeah, I meant to use set /p :P